# Unable to get a match, regex

Tags: regex

I've got text: (PRD:TLK-XX138832)

However I can't seem to get a match and the brackets are causing a problem. I'm new to regex and have tried multiple times to get a match unsuccessfully.

I thought this would work but hasn't: `\(PRD:[.]\)`

Is my understanding of `.` incorrect?

I've also tried `[a-zA-Z0-9\-]` but this doesn't work either, along with a few other combinations?

(TLK-XX138832 can be anything, as long as it has PRD: and the brackets.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your understanding of `.` seems incorrect. It is a special character which is interpreted as "any char". Except in a character class (in square brackets) where it means "just the `.` character".

A correct regex for what you want might be:

```
\(PRD:[^)]*\)
```

Here, `[^)]` is a character class meaning "any character except `)`".

What you did try to do was:

```
\(PRD:.*\)
```

But it can match too much, for example, that could match:

```
(PRD:FOO) (PRD:BAR)
```

Because the `*` is greedy (it tries to match as much as possible).

If your regex engine supports it, you could try the (slightly more readable) non-greedy variant:

```
\(PRD:.*?\)
```

Which is functionally equivalent to the first solution.

Comment: What does the additional bracket in [^)] do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to append `*` after a match to specify to match multiple occurrences.

Use:

```
\(PRD:[A-Z0-9-]*\)
```